# How to make scully.io work on github pages?

Tags: angular, github-pages, scully, scullyio

I'm trying to add scully to my portfolio hosted on github pages. When I'm disabling javascript in the browser, everything stops working (website is not rendered at all). Github requires all deployable files to be in /docs folder, I've put all my scully files there. You can find the repo structure here: https://github.com/jakub-wisniowski/portfolio

and the website here: https://jakub-wisniowski.github.io/portfolio/

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: So when you run scully, do you get any errors? It looks like the routes are picked up correctly, but all your index pages are basically empty.. never seen this...

Comment: @MikeOne scully does not throw any errors, there was a warning reminding to use option --scanRoutes. I used it once and nothing has changed, then ran it again and some changes have been made to index pages, but the content still isn't displayed

Comment: I’m seeing some more issues reported on scully gitter about this. Maybe useful to have a peek there? https://gitter.im/scullyio/community

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use **Scully Publish** GitHub Action - https://github.com/marketplace/actions/scully-publish

```
name: Scully Publish

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - uses: cmgriffing/scully-gh-pages-action@v1
        with:
          access-token: ${{ secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN }}
```